# Append column of arrays in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of arrays such as:

```
| A | B | C |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| [0,1,2,3]  | [1,2,5,6]    | [0,1,4,5] |
| [0,0,6,3]  | [0,2,0,4]    | [3,8,7,1] |
| [1,0,2,1]  | [0,0,2,0]    | [1,2,1,1] |
```

I want to convert to get the unique and count values of the whole dataframe.

```
| value | count |
|------ |------|
|0| 9|
|1| 9|
|2| 6|
|3| 3|
|4| 2|
|5| 2|
|6| 2|
|7| 1|
|8| 1|
```

Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking about df.nunique()

Comment: try combining `df.explode` and `df.value_counts`

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [`pd.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to expand arrays, combine columns into one with [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and then count the values with [`pd.Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A': [np.random.randint(9, size=5)] * 5,
        'B': [np.random.randint(9, size=5)] * 5,
        'C': [np.random.randint(9, size=5)] * 5
    }
)

df = df.explode(df.columns)
pd.concat([df[col] for col in df.columns]).value_counts()
```

Note: you can only run `df.explode` with a list of columns if you're using `pandas >= 1.3.0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = [[0,1,2,3],[0,0,6,3],[1,0,2,1]]
b = [[1,2,5,6],[0,2,0,4],[0,0,2,0]]
c = [[0,1,4,5],[3,8,7,1],[1,2,1,1]]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'a': a,
     'b': b,
     'c': c
    })

pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(df.values)).\
explode(0)[0].\
value_counts().\
to_frame().\
sort_index().\
reset_index().\
rename(columns={"index": "value", 0: "count"})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten the dataframe values to 1D array and then use `np.unique` to count value count

```py
val, cnt = np.unique(np.array(df.values.tolist()).flatten(), return_counts=True)
out = pd.DataFrame({'value': val, 'count': cnt})
```

```
print(out)

   value  count
0      0     10
1      1      9
2      2      6
3      3      3
4      4      2
5      5      2
6      6      2
7      7      1
8      8      1
```